# wagtail snippets Add all snippet entity by snippet choose panel in one shot not one by one

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield, wagtail-snippet

I m using wagtail 2.8

I have article as snippet and i want to create articles page add all in easy way with out need to add them one by one (i have 400 )

i am using stream Field with StructBlock

```
class NewsListBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    slug     = blocks.CharBlock(help_text='Block Slug')
    items    = blocks.ListBlock(SnippetChooserBlock(News))

    class Meta:
        label = 'News'
        icon = 'doc-full'
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management) to read and load the data into your model.